# ClassCastException when i query

Tags: java, hibernate

i have below code:

```
public float getTotalCash(String year) {


        CustomerPayment cp = null;

        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();


        try {
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  like '%" + year + "' and c.type='Cash'");
            cp = (CustomerPayment) q.uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return totalCashAmount = cp.getAmount();

    }
```

However, it gives ClassCastException.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to tekirmobile.CustomerPayment
    at tekirmobile.clController.getTotalCash(clController.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What might be the reason? Why i get this error? Is there a reason of that error because of float returning?What might be the reason? Why i get this error? What might be the reason? Why i get this error?

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: Try removing `select c.type, c.date, sum(c.amount) ` from your query. It's also better to use named params and let hibernate set the arguments for you.

Comment: so if i delete them how can i sum amount column?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting parts of the `c` instead of SELECTing a `c` object.  [Here are some examples of valid HQL.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)  I think this will work the way you want:

```
"from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  like '%" + year + "' and c.type='Cash'"
```

But, that's not really great to do either because you can do a sql injection attack here.  You should turn that `year` into a variable.  [Here are a bunch of examples of how to do that.](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)

Comment: so if i delete them how can i sum amount column?

Comment: Where do you expect the value of the sum column to go?

Comment: i need to sum amount column

Comment: @user2341009 Your reply did not answer my question.

Comment: i need to put summation to my CustomerPayment.amount ?

Comment: from CustomerPayment c  where c.date  like '%2013' and c.type='Cash'" this gives error

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting CustomerPayment.type, CustomerPayment.date, sum(CustomerPayment.amount), not CustomerPayment object

Comment: so if i delete them how can i sum amount column?

Comment: You don't have to delete it, you just can't cast it to CustomerPayment. It probably returns array with size 3.

Comment: so what is the proper way to do that? Do i need to select what?

Comment: get a book user2341009  or go thru a tutorial this is pretty basic